# code in save_model executed on second save, not first

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-guardian

i defined a save_model in my UserAdmin to change object level permissions for users.

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        obj.save()
        allprojects = Project.objects.all()
        projects = obj.workingproject.all()
        remove_perm("view_project", obj, allprojects)
        assign_perm("view_project", obj, projects)
        obj.save()
```

remove_perm and assign_perm are shortcuts from django-guardian, workingproject is a M2M field of user.

The problem: when selecting different projects and saving the permissions are not changed, but pressing the save button a second time makes the changes as wanted. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by overriding `save_related`

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    super(UserAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
    obj = form.instance
    allprojects = Project.objects.all()
    projects = obj.workingproject.all()
    remove_perm("view_project", obj, allprojects)
    assign_perm("view_project", obj, projects)
```

In `save_related`, Django is removing M2M that are already there and setting new ones. So changes doing in `save_model` and `save` will not reflect.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could you explain why my solution didnt work?